# Can Someone Explain How the Grid Project works in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am looking at the windows 8 grid project that comes with VS2012 and trying to understand it. I don't know too much about XAML so I getting quite easily lost of where binding code is happening and such.

```
<Page.Resources>

    <!--
        Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
        of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
    -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="TopItems"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Click="Header_Click"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>

    <!-- Vertical scrolling list only used when snapped -->
    <ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Margin="0,-10,0,0"
        Padding="10,0,0,60"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard80ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="7,7,0,0">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Click="Header_Click"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
    </Grid>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

            <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="96,137,10,56"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <!--
                The back button and title have different styles when snapped, and the list representation is substituted
                for the grid displayed in all other view states
            -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

The first area I don't understand is this

```
  <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Groups}"
            IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="TopItems"
            d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

I don't get where this  `Source="{Binding Groups}"` is actually coming from (I am not even sure how to find the code F12 does not work).

Same with the `d:Source` not sure 100% what is going on there as well.

The next part is in the gridview and again with the binding.

```
<GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,137,40,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
```

I see that Items Source is using that groupItemsViewSource but not sure how it is parsing the data into the grid look but not sure how.

The next part I don't get is how does it figure out what layout to use. I see this in the comments

```
    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
<!-- Vertical scrolling list only used when snapped -->
```

I am sure if I look even deeper into it I will find more I don't understand but maybe when I understand this stuff I will understand more(especially once I understand this binding stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I don't get where this Source="{Binding Groups}" is actually coming
from (I am not even sure how to find the code F12 does not work).*

Note at the top of the page:

```
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

which sets the context for the binding on that page to the `DefaultViewModel` property of the page. In the code behind for the page you'll see

```
this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;
```

where `sampleDataGroups` is a list (IEnumerable) of groups (type `SampleDataGroup`) returned from a method call. Now you also have,

```
<CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="TopItems"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

and here "Groups" refers to the key that indexes the `DefaultViewModel`, so it's going to use that subset of the `DefaultViewModel`.  Furthermore, each item in the CollectionViewSource itself contains a collection, and those collections are surfaced to the binding engine at whatever property `ItemsPath` specifies, namely, `TopItems`.

Now from the GridView binding:

```
<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
```

you noted that the data is coming from that specific instance of a CollectionViewSource named `groupedItemsViewSource` (which in this case is equivalent to `this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"]`).  If you look at the header template a bit later, you'll see:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
     ...
```

The `Title` binding refers to the property of an element in the `ItemsSource` collection, so `this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"][i].Title`

`ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"` in the GridView binding governs how the inner collection items are displayed.  You'll have to crack that style open (in `Common/StandardStyles.xaml`) to see that it references properties of a `SampleDataItem`, essentially leading to `this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"][i].TopItems[j]`.

The `d:` prefix refers to design time data (well, a namespace that includes classes that manage it); it's what allows you do see the data in the designer without running your application. So at design time the data you are seeing actually comes from `SampleDataSource.AllGroups`.

As for the comments about scrolling, that gets into the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209021.aspx), each state essentially being a different take on the UI; states transition via a bit of code you can find inside of `LayoutAwarePage.cs` look for [GotoState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get where this Source="{Binding Groups}" is actually coming from

Bindings target the `DataContext` of the element -- to find it, you typically scan up the XAML to find where DataContext was last set.  So in this case, it must either set on the `Page` element somehow.   (The DataContext can also be set from code-behind, although I'd be surprised if that were the case in the VS sample project.)

> Same with the d:Source not sure 100% what is going on there as well.

The `d` prefix is referring to design-time data.  Check for the `SampleDataSource`, that's where you'll find the design-time instance of `AllGroups`.

> not sure how it is parsing the data into the grid

The Grid auto-generates its columns based on the properties of its row data type.